# Would ( intValue ( "." intValue )? ) be read as 1.9 ?? Also, how to add attribute to Heat Template

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, heat, openstack-heat

Is this a regEx?

As per [Mesos' documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/attributes-resources/):

```
scalar : floatValue

floatValue : ( intValue ( "." intValue )? ) | ...
```

Would I read it the same way as I'd read the scalar via the [documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/attributes-resources/)?

I'm trying to figure out how to add attribute to Mesos Cluster nodes, but the sample Heat Template I have has nothing to the tune of 'node attributes' in it, and I'm kind of shooting for the moon here.

As It goes into a HEAT template, would each attribute for a specific node be added into the preferences section? I have been trying to find this answer for days now, and all my attempts seem to fail when I deploy the template.

I have tried adding an attributes section, to no avail:

```
parameters:

  name:
    type: string

resources:

  # Boot script
  boot_script:
    etc, etc...

attributes:
  server_group:
    group_1
```

Comment: What "the sample Heat Template" you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would ( intValue ( “.” intValue )? ) be read as 1.9 ?

**Yes**

This definition is a [formal grammar definiton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar) of a scalar value. You can find similar definition for programming lanugage for example [Golang looks like this (from antlr-4 examples)](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/1f7290565c5cc14970edeba8385e34886eea432c/golang/Golang.g4#L822-L847)

To read grammar this you need to take a look at whole definition

```
scalar : floatValue

floatValue : ( intValue ( "." intValue )? ) | ...

intValue : [0-9]+
```

and flatten it to following regexp (I do not know what `...` means):

```
scalar : [0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?
```

[image: regexp] [source](https://regexper.com/#%5B0-9%5D%2B(%5C.%5B0-9%5D%2B)%3F)

> How to add attribute to Heat Template

Not enoutght information to answer this.

Comment: Did you create this diagram yourself? Is there a centralized location of these if not? I'm going to reverse-image search it and report back. thanks!

Edit: http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2017x06x01Regex

That just changed the way I see regexes.

Thanks so much for that <br>

Comment: @conedmiro I used regexper. I added link to answer.